# WCF UDP, Encryption and Serialization

Tags: c#, wcf, serialization

I have a particular requirement which I was not sure how to fulfill it.

Scenario:
- I am to use WCF UDP binding to multicast message across the network.
- The message to be send across has to be encrypted

I have managed to multicast messages across the network using WCF UDP. However I am stuck at the encryption portion.

I have a few solutions but all of them have a bit of a problem:

1) Use SecurityBindingElement of WCF and include into the BindingCollection. But I am not sure that what security is supported for udp binding.

2) encrypt the data before the ServiceContract call. But that would mean I will need to change the DataContract and the size of the message will change.

For example:

```
[DataContract]
public class Old_Person_Contract
{
   [EnumMember]
   string name { get; set;}

   [EnumMember]
   byte age { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class New_Person_Contract
{
    [EnumMember]
    string name { get; set; }

    [EnumMember]
    byte[] age { get; set; }
}
```

Notice the age field has changed from byte to byte[] and if I used the AesCryptoServiceProvider to do my encrpytion, I will increase the message size by a few more bytes

3) Modify the WCF serialization to encrypt after serialize. Is this possible and how to do it?

Any help to help me tackle this problem is welcome.
Thanks